# Get id, name from master table - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The association is has follows

```
Company has_many company_commodities
CompanyCommodity belongs to Company
CompanyCommodity belongs to Commodity
```

Consider that company1 has an entry in the **company_commodities** table.

Now in the **decorator file**, i need to get the commodity name and id of that record.

I have implemented as follows.

```
company1 = Company.find(1)
arr = co.company_commodities.map(&:commodity).pluck(:name, :id)
arr.map { |a| { name: a[0], id: a[1] } }
```

This produces the output as

```
[{:name=>"Pharmaceuticals", :id=>25},
 {:name=>"Medical Devices", :id=>26}]
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_commodities
  has_many :commodities, through: :company_commodities
end

class CompanyCommodity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commodity
  belongs_to :company
end

company = Company.find(1)
# this returns the object you can access by arr.first.id, arr.first.name
arr = company.commodities.select(:name, :id)
# if you want to access as hash, usage: arr.first['id'], arr.first['name']
arr = company.commodities.select(:name, :id).as_json
```

You can get the commodities association by using `through`, then you can use `select` to filter the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the associations as below

```
class Company
  has_many :company_commodities
  has_many :commodities, through: :company_commodities
end

class CompanyCommodity
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :commodity
end
```

And query the records as

```
 company1 = Company.find(1)
 arr = co.commodities.pluck(:name, :id)
 arr.reduce([]) { |array, el| array << [[:name, :id], el].to_h}
```

Comment: `[[:name, :id], el].to_h` could possibly be changed to `[:name, :id].zip(el).to_h` but right now your code will produce `{:name=> :id, "Pharmaceuticals"=>25}` which is not the intended result and `map` would be considered more idiomatic than `reduce([])` in this case